# Include CSS file directly into template?

Tags: smarty

I've tried searching for how to include a CSS file **directly** into the template, but none of the answers are very good. I do **not** want to include the CSS file using `<link>`, I want to include it directly into the template. I also do not want to read the entire file into a variable and output the variable in the template.

I tried doing it like this

```
<style>{include "$ROOT_DIR/public/css/all.css}</style>
```

but then Smarty tries to parse it as a template, which obviously won't work because of the `{` and `}` in the CSS file.

I can't put `{literal} ... {/literal}` around the include, because then Smarty will just output the include command literally. And obviously I don't want to put the `{literal} ... {/literal}` in the CSS file, since it's not CSS.

I could read the file into a variable and output that in the template, but that seems like a very backwards way of doing things, and probably not very efficient.

Surely, there must be some way to include a file without parsing it as a template?!

Comment: Are you looking for `{fetch}`?

Comment: @Progman I don't think so? How would I use that to include a CSS file in the template, from within the template itself? I simply want to do a PHP `include`, without any parsing or anything else.

Comment: So `{fetch file='path/to/yourFile.css'}` is not working? Please [edit] your question to include the result, when you try to use `{fetch}` in your template.

Comment: @Progman Thanks, it seems it does indeed work. Couldn't find how to use in in the documentation though. All I could find for `fetch` was to use it in PHP code to get the output of a template. Doesn't say anything there that it can be used to include files, or perhaps I just cant find the right documentation page. But at least now it's working!

Comment: It's a template command, see https://smarty-php.github.io/smarty/designers/language-custom-functions/language-function-fetch.html